# Mkdir error, Permission denied

Tags: bash, mkdir

Hi guys my code is as follows:

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "What directory?"
read $dir

mkdir -p "$dir"/Air/Output
mkdir -p "$dir"/Oxy/Output

echo "done"
```

im getting the error "permission denied" Is it a problem

Answer (score 2):

You should `read dir`, not `read $dir`.

With `read $dir`, your variable will not be set and with an empty `dir` variable, you attempt to create a directory from root `/Air/Output` which cause the permission denied.

As sjsam suggest, you may also add a prompt to `read` with its `-p` option :

```
read -p "What directory?" dir
```